# Should I separate cron into its own docker container?

Tags: docker, cron

Suppose I have a Docker container with Nginx or PostgresQL. I need Cron to delete old log files. Where should I run cron? In the same container inside an entrypoint script? In its onw container? Outside docker?

Running in outside Docker will defeat Docker's control over configurations. I will have to use some other configuration management system to pin its config.

Comment: docker containers should not preserve any persistent data. set nginx to stream the logs to stdout instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to rethink why you actually need a cron job. 
Why do you have old log files inside of your container? One of the best practices with building applications inside containers is the fact of logging everything towards stdout/stderr. This way you keep the paradigm of 1 container = 1 process and your log management is a responsibility of docker and/or your host.

You can do this fairly easy by either:

- reconfiguring your application to log to /dev/stdout
- linking your application log file /var/log/nginx/access.log to /dev/stdout in your dockerfile

```
ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

If you actually need to log towards a location inside your container, a good practice could be to log towards a shared volume. Then run a cron job that spins up a container which also mounts this volume and cleans the logs. You can schedule this clean-up container with a cron job.

If you use some kind of orchestrator like Kubernetes it'd be done with a Scheduled pod which does exactly this.

Comment: 1 container = 1 process paradigm has reasons to be applied. I found them listed here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container
However I do not see how these reasons are applied here. Cron jobs may not be easily decoupled from the main service

Comment: A related question is whether I should run Certbot in a separate container from Nginx.